# CSRF middleware token missing?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm novice adapting a simple address book database program using Django from a course I've done on Codemy.

I have a page where I enter the names, surnames etc together with a DELETE and EDIT button next to each address. There's no problem when I click the EDIT button (the form populates automatically and takes me to website/edit1,2,3,4 etc/), but when I click the 'edit' button after editing the addressee info, I get the error as below. The **btn1** is the name="btn1" of the button as indicated.

`GET /edit/3?csrfmiddlewaretoken=b4IkMxxxxxxxxxxxDHrDIgRnjvEWr53rL&**btn1**=140 HTTP/1.1" 200 5751`

Here is my views file

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import List
from .forms import ListForm
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def home(request):
    all_items = List.objects.all
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'all_items': all_items})

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'about.html', {})

def edit(request, item_id):
    if request.method =='POST':
        item = List.objects.get(pk=item_id)
        form = ListForm(request.POST or None, instance=item)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, ('Item Had Been Edited'))
            return redirect('home')

    else:
        item = List.objects.get(pk=item_id)
        return render(request, 'edit.html', {'item': item})

def delete(request, item_id):
    item = List.objects.get(pk=item_id)
    item.delete()
    return redirect('home')
```

...And here is the edit.html file

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}To-Do-List | Edit {% endblock %}

{% block content %}

  {% if item %}
    {{ item.item }}
  <form class="needs-validation" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
          <label for="validationCustom01">First name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom01" value="{{ item.First_name }}" required>
          <div class="valid-feedback">
            Looks good!
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
          <label for="validationCustom02">Last name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom02" value="{{ item.Surname }}" required>
          <div class="valid-feedback">
            Looks good!
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
          <label for="validationCustom03">Street</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ item.Street }}" id="validationCustom03" required>
          <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Please provide a valid city.
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
          <label for="validationCustom03">Town</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ item.Town }}" id="validationCustom03" required>
          <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Please provide a valid city.
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
          <label for="validationCustom05">Province</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ item.Province }}" id="validationCustom05" required>
          <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Please provide a valid zip.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
          <label for="validationCustom05">Postal code</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ item.Postal_code }}" id="validationCustom05" required>
          <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Please provide a valid zip.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" type="hidden" value="" name='btn1'>Edit</button>
    </form>

  <script>
  // Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
  (function() {
    'use strict';
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
      // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
      var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
      // Loop over them and prevent submission
      var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
        form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
          if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
          }
          form.classList.add('was-validated');
        }, false);
      });
    }, false);
  })();
  </script>

  {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

I cannot locate an issue with the CSRF token. it is included just like the tutorial on the edit.html page. Not even sure if the issue is with the token?

I've gone through the tutorial time and again and cannot see an issue.

I'm a noob, so any info would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Normally, when you save information after editing it in a form, you should "post" your data to the server.

It appears your form method is not set which default to get. It should be set to post.

```
<form method="post">...</form>
```

This being said, your view should also be configured accordingly. Without more details, it is hard to provide deeper answer.